# How to print Trace32 terminal view to a file?

Tags: arm, jtag, trace32, lauterbach

I have a script that initializes terminal and prints information in it in Trace32 terminal and I cannot edit that file. I am using `term.write` command to log the contents in terminal window to a file. But it does log the information that were written before executing this command.

So, I tried to `Printer.file` and `winprint.term.view` commands. Now I get this error.

> terminal window with this configuration already open

What should I do to log all the contents of terminal (including contents that were already written and will be written in the terminal) to a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the content from a window in TRACE32 while using the debugger ***interactively***, click on the context menu, and choose "To Clipboard all". Then open a text editor and paste your clipboard to an empty document (Ctrl+V).
[image]

---

If you want to get the content of a window in TRACE32 via a ***PRACTICE script*** use the command `PRinTer.FILE <FilenName> ASCIIE` (as you did) and then the command `WinPRT <WindowName> /ALL`.

The pre-command WinPRINT creates a new window on the printer, which will not give what you want with Terminal windows. The command **WinPRT** however, actually sends the content of an open window to the printer (and the printer can be redirected to a file).

The tricky thing with **WinPRT** is to know the name of your window. The command **WinPOS** allows you set the name for next opening window. So I recommend to use **WinPOS** in the script opening your terminal window. But since you can't change that script use the command **WinPAGE.List** to get the names of all open windows.

E.g. In the following **WinPAGE.List** you can see that the window opened with TERM.VIEW has the window-name "W000".
 
[image]
Thus, I can get the content of my terminal window with

```
PRinTer.FILE "C:\temp\mywindow.txt ASCIIE
WinPRT W000 /ALL
```

Note, that window names are case sensitive.

The window names starting with a capital 'W' followed by three decimal digits are set by TRACE32 in the order they appear. So if you want to be sure that your terminal window always gets the same name, ensure that no window is open before opening your terminal window with your script. You can close all windows with **WinPAGE.RESet**.

So all together you get:

```
WinPAGE.RESet
DO "C:\T32\user\my_script_to_open_the_terminal.cmm"
PRinTer.FILE "C:\temp\mywindow.txt ASCIIE
WinPRT W000 /ALL
```

If you script is only opening one terminal window and no other window, I recommend to do this:

```
WinPOS ,,,,,,myTerminal    
DO "C:\T32\user\my_script_to_open_the_terminal.cmm"
PRinTer.FILE "C:\temp\mywindow.txt ASCIIE
WinPRT myTerminal /ALL
```

Comment: Is it possible to get WindowName by using AreaName?

Comment: You can't get the WindowName by using an AreaName. Consider that there could be more than one window showing the the same message area.

Answer (score 0):

I am late, but figured out the answer.

```
&LOGFILENAME=OS.PPF()+".log" ; so, filename here is "<this_current_path_filename_with_extension>.log"
PRINT " Printing to log file: &(LOGFILENAME)"
PRinTer.FILE &LOGFILENAME ASCIIE

; select and open display the AREA you want to print to file; here it is default T32 log area A000
AREA.Select A000
AREA.View A000
WinPrint.AREA.View
;AREA.CLEAR ;if you want to clear the view for next set of prints
```

Alternatively, in real-time, write-to-file is

```
OPEN #1 OS.PPF()+".log" /CREATE  ; so, filename here is "<this_current_path_filename_with_extension>.log"
;...
WRITE #1 "Hello World - it is " DATE.TIME()
;how many ever WRITE's you want in the code 
;...
;...
WRITE #1 " BYE"
;...
CLOSE #1
```